# new fineuploader javascript errors in chrome

Tags: fine-uploader

2 weeks  ago we started getting this error with fineuploader code but only in chrome.
I assume a chrome update kicked  it off.

I tried newest version of jquery and new custom build of fineuploader with everything in it but error stays.
It stops the uploaded from displaying

Any help. Hard to believe we're the only ones butcan't find any bug reports etc.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property
>   'showAutoRetryNote' of false.
>
> //Calling code:

```
    manualuploader = jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
                    template: "qq-template-manual-noedit",
                    autoUpload: false,
                    disableCancelForFormUploads: true,
                    maxConnections: 1,
                    multiple: false,
                    retry: false,
                    request: {
                        endpoint: '/onlinemarketing/updatenewsletterheader.ashx'
                    },
                    validation: {
                        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
                    }
           }
                }).on('submit', function (na, id) {
                    if (qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews) {
                      jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploader("drawThumbnail", id, jQuery('.nlhi'), 700, false);
                    }
                    pendingUpload = true;
                    jQuery('#triggerUpload').show();
                    jQuery('#cancelPreview').show();
                     jQuery(".nlhi").unbind('error'); // dont show the default image again if the image failed to upload this handler is only really for when teh page loads at the start
                    currentImageId = id;
                }).on('complete', function (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {
                    if(xhr.success){
                        pendingUpload = false;
                        jQuery('#triggerUpload').hide();
                        jQuery('#cancelPreview').hide();
                        _noImageAvailableForEzine = false;
                        if (!qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews) {
                        alert( xhr.savePath);
                           jQuery('.nlhi').attr("src", xhr.savePath);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                     alert(xhr.message);
                    }

                });



            jQuery('#triggerUpload').click(function () {
                manualuploader.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
            });
```

Gaelmart

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by an error in your inititialization code.  The error message gives a good clue as to what the problem is.

You're assigning a Boolean value to the `retry` option.  Fine Uploader expects an object.  See the retry option in the docs for information on correctly configuring this option (http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options.html#retry).